# Foreign Key issue in a virtual many-to-many user relationship when removing user

Tags: doctrine

In my Symfony app, I have to handle some kind of friendship requests. It's basically a many to many relation between users, but with an `accepted` boolean property, and a `createdAt` DateTime, hence why I created an independent "friendship" entity instead of just a Many to many relations in the user entity.

Here is the issue though: I have a `Sender` property (one to many relation to user) and a `recipient` property (one to many relation to user as well). I set the `orphanRemoval` to true on the Friendships property in the user.

However, if I delete a user with only friendships where he was the sender, it works well and deletes the friendship entities. But if he is a recipient of a friend request, it just doesn't work and returns a Foreign Key constraint error, more precisely

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
> update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`portail`.`friendship`, CONSTRAINT `FK_7234A45FE92F8F78`
> FOREIGN KEY (`recipient_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)).

I reckon it has something to do with the fact that user appears twice in my friendship entity, and obviously, it seems like only the sender is mentioned in the `addFriendship()` / `removeFriendship()` methods, but I'm not sure how to fix it, and I'd like to know if maybe I didn't tackle the issue the right way, and what I could do to change this and make it work (ie: remove all Friendships related to the User, whether he's the sender or recipient).

Below is the friendship entity, as well as the part of the User entity mentioning the Friendship entity relation.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\FriendshipRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=FriendshipRepository::class)
 */
class Friendship
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="friendships")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private ?User $sender;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="friendships")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private ?User $recipient;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private ?bool $accepted;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable")
     */
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSender(): ?User
    {
        return $this->sender;
    }

    public function setSender(?User $sender): self
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRecipient(): ?User
    {
        return $this->recipient;
    }

    public function setRecipient(?User $recipient): self
    {
        $this->recipient = $recipient;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccepted(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->accepted;
    }

    public function setAccepted(bool $accepted): self
    {
        $this->accepted = $accepted;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeImmutable $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Part of the user

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Friendship::class, mappedBy="sender", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $friendships;
```

```
    /**
     * @return Collection|Friendship[]
     */
    public function getFriendships(): Collection
    {
        return $this->friendships;
    }

    public function addFriendship(Friendship $friendship): self
    {
        if (!$this->friendships->contains($friendship)) {
            $this->friendships[] = $friendship;
            $friendship->setSender($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFriendship(Friendship $friendship): self
    {
        if ($this->friendships->removeElement($friendship)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($friendship->getSender() === $this) {
                $friendship->setSender(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Both relations have `inversedBy="friendships"` I think you need to use a different field for each (i.e. `friendRequestsSent` & `friendRequestsRecieved`.

Comment: That is what I figured after working a bit more on it. I'll try it tonight and post an answer if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arleigh was indeed correct. What I did wrong was set the same name, ie `Friendships`, while updating my `friendship` entity to get both relations in the user, whether he was a `sender` or `recipient`. I thought this would allow me to more easily get all `friendships` related to a user in my controllers and twig template, regardless of them being a `recipient` or a `sender` but in the end, all it did was make it all go wrong.

I fixed it by having two separate properties in my user, the `friendshipRequestsSent`(mapped by the `sender` field of the `Friendship` entity) and `friendshipRequestsReceived` (mapped by the `recpient` field of the `Friendship` entity) as well as the methods and typing of the properties  associated. This is what it looks like in my `User` entity now

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Friendship::class, mappedBy="sender", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $friendshipRequestsSent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Friendship::class, mappedBy="recipient", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $friendshipRequestsReceived;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userSkills = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->experiences = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->missions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->friendshipRequestsSent = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->friendshipRequestsReceived = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

```
    /**
     * @return Collection|Friendship[]
     */
    public function getFriendshipRequestsSent(): Collection
    {
        return $this->friendshipRequestsSent;
    }

    public function addFriendshipRequestSent(Friendship $friendship): self
    {
        if (!$this->friendshipRequestsSent->contains($friendship)) {
            $this->friendshipRequestsSent[] = $friendship;
            $friendship->setSender($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFriendshipRequestSent(Friendship $friendship): self
    {
        if ($this->friendshipRequestsSent->removeElement($friendship)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($friendship->getSender() === $this) {
                $friendship->setSender(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return Collection|Friendship[]
     */
    public function getFriendshipRequestsReceived(): Collection
    {
        return $this->friendshipRequestsReceived;
    }

    public function addFriendshipRequestReceived(Friendship $friendship): self
    {
        if (!$this->friendshipRequestsReceived->contains($friendship)) {
            $this->friendshipRequestsReceived[] = $friendship;
            $friendship->setSender($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFriendshipRequestReceived(Friendship $friendship): self
    {
        if ($this->friendshipRequestsReceived->removeElement($friendship)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($friendship->getSender() === $this) {
                $friendship->setSender(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

And this is how my `Friendship` entity `sender` and `recipient` properties are declared

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="friendshipRequestsSent")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private ?User $sender;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="friendshipRequestsReceived")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private ?User $recipient;
```